# Retrieve a "IsClient=false" EntityManager for unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, devforce

We would like to perform unit testing of some server-side components that are performing named queries, these components constructors receive an EntityManager.

Our unit testing framework is based upon NUnit and we are running the tests in non-distributed mode to simulate a 2-tier deployment. Unfortunately, creating an EntityManager from the unit test code will always produce a "Client" manager, while we would need a "Server" version (ie. the same as the one you would get in a server method). As we get a client version, some named queries inside the code we are testing are rejected due to security constraints on the model.

Is there a good way to retrieve the EntityManager and somehow simulate the server behavior on unit test side? The best I came so far was calling a dedicated server method, store the EntityServer somewhere in a global variable and use that from the unit tests.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

As you've found, DF isn't particularly unit test friendly and the approach you're using is a good workaround.

DevForce "server-side" components, such as IEntityLoginManager, EntityServerQueryInterceptors, etc., will always be called (if found) regardless of actual deployment.  So even when running 2-tier unit tests
DF will fire up an in-memory EntityServer and look for server-side components in order to fulfill a request from an EntityManager.

If you're running into issues with ClientCanQuery authorization checks this means the default EntityServerQueryInterceptor authorization logic is kicking in.  You can implement a custom interceptor for testing purposes using the "composition context" feature of DevForce.  With a custom test interceptor you could override the default authorization logic to allow these queries to run.  There's some info on using composition contexts with testing [here](http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/discovery-context).

Alternately, if you want to stretch the meaning of "unit" test and since server-side components will be invoked regardless, you can write simple client side unit tests which trigger the specific server-side logic you're looking to test.
For example, a simple named query invoked on the client will cause specific logic in your named query provider and/or query interceptor to run, and the test can verify the results.